# How to draw a 3D square as per user's input in Python?

Tags: python, 3d, python-turtle

I want to draw a 3D square according to the user's input of the x, y, z coordinates using Python, but I have no idea how to draw them! I checked out other related questions on StackOverflow and google, but couldn't find the correct info.

Here are the sample coordinates:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Need it to look like this, a cube drawn on a 2D page according to the user's input

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: can we use turtle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this?

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                  [1, -1, -1 ],
                  [1, 1, -1],
                  [-1, 1, -1],
                  [-1, -1, 1],
                  [1, -1, 1 ],
                  [1, 1, 1],
                  [-1, 1, 1]])
# user input goes here
P = [
  [0 , 0 ,  1],
  [0,  1 , 0],
  [1,  0 , 0]
 ]

Z = np.zeros((8,3))
for i in range(8): Z[i,:] = np.dot(points[i,:],P)
Z = 10.0*Z

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

r = [-1,1]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(r, r)
# plot vertices
ax.scatter3D(Z[:, 0], Z[:, 1], Z[:, 2])

# list of sides' polygons of figure
verts = [[Z[0],Z[1],Z[2],Z[3]],
 [Z[4],Z[5],Z[6],Z[7]], 
 [Z[0],Z[1],Z[5],Z[4]], 
 [Z[2],Z[3],Z[7],Z[6]], 
 [Z[1],Z[2],Z[6],Z[5]],
 [Z[4],Z[7],Z[3],Z[0]]]

# plot sides
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, 
 facecolors='cyan', linewidths=1, edgecolors='r', alpha=.25))

ax.set_axis_off()

plt.savefig('spec',bbox_inches='tight',transparent=True, pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Oh lemme see, if you like this post, please upvore so I can comment after getting 50 reputation

Comment: The cube is made in a graph, that is really awesome but I want the cube drawn on a 2D page

Comment: So what is the thing you are trying to do first, what is the purpose of the cube and where will it be used?

Comment: so the program asks for the x and y and z axis, and the program draws a 3d cube according to the user's input, can be in pixels too. I edited the question, you can get a clear idea

Comment: ok, i updated the code as per your question update, this will create a cube, and then save it to a image file where you can then present it to the user.

Comment: exactly! thanks alot! and btw do you know kturtle? can we combine kturtle to draw the same cube, on a 2d sheet

Comment: so the cube cannot be rotated, its just the picture of a 3d cube on a 2d paper, like we draw a cube in the maths paper

Comment: you can change the P variable to rotate the cube.

Comment: andi, how can we use turtle, can u answer the same question?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with turtle